# SQL Server: how auto incrementing a particular column without using IDENTITY method?

Tags: sql-server

How to auto increment a particular column without using `IDENTITY` method in SQL Server?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do that but it is unclear which is the best one for you because we don't know a lot about what you're doing. Why can't you use IDENTITY in the first place?

Comment: Using `IDENTITY` is ***THE*** solution on SQL Server (or `SEQUENCES` in SQL Server 2012) - why not use it, if it's available? Why re-invent the wheel yet again?

Answer (score 3):

1. Using [sequences](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) if you're using SQL Server 2012.
2. Using GUIDs and [NEWID()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function.

Answer provided by [sqlhint.com](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/sqlserver/how-to/auto-increment-column-without-using-identity)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen instances where people have used an instead of insert trigger, which will then check the max value for that column to determine the next value.  I'd personally not recommend this approach though, especially in a high transnational system

Answer (score -2):

Before making the insert, you can search for the max value of this column and add 1 for the new row.

Comment: I upvoted but **NOTE** this is prone to race conditioning and is not recommended in an environment where multiple users might insert data

Comment: It works but within a transaction and setting the right serialization level. However, I'm not a fun of this method.

Comment: That is completely true, nrathaus. You have to be careful with this solution, depending on the concurrence...

Comment: This will create duplicate IDs if you delete the last inserted row then try to add a new one

Comment: @Panagiotis, I desagree: user3032211 doesn't say that the column is an ID, but anyway, if you delete the last row and create a new one, it takes a new value again (the same than you recently deleted).

Comment: That's what duplicate means. Any related entries that referenced the original ID will now point to the new entry, which is rarely what you want

Comment: The question is for a particular column, not for an ID. No relations, no references. Just a column. What I said is valid if there is no concurrence